# Simple classification with Kafka Streams

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, state, apache-kafka-streams

I am currently trying to find a straight forward and performant way to classify records with Kafka Streams.
All the records contain at least an `id` and a `failed` property.
(`id` is just a String and `failed` is Boolean)

The idea is to, in the beginning, classify all the incoming records as "message".
Once one of the incoming records has the failed field set, this should be "persisted" somewhere and the record should be classified as "failure".

Every from now on incoming record with the same `id` should be classified as "failure" as well, no matter if the `failed` property is set.

I'm thinking about either using the internal State Store of Kafka Streams (together with the interactive query feature) or an external database that will be queried each time a record comes in. I think the State Store of Kafka itself sounds like a more lightweight solution.

Here is a little concept sketch to, hopefully, help understand the problem.
[image]

Does someone have an idea on how to tackle this the right way?

Thank you
All the best
- Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach sounds good to me. Don't think you need IQ feature though. Just define a custom `Transformer` and attach a key-value store to it. During processing, if you get a message with `failed=true` you put the ID into the store. For each incoming message with `failed=false` you additionally check the store to check if there was a previous failed message with the same ID.

To persist failed messages, you just split your stream into two (maybe use `branch()` and write `failed` messages into a special topic.

Comment: Thank you very much Matthias, this approach looks really clean and solid. I'm implementing this right now.